# can't cache static files using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching

I am new to caching and i am trying to test how files would be cached so i have created a simple php web page to test if i can cache the `css` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="heading">Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and i have created an htaccess file then added these lines from [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess)

```
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Expires headers                                                    |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve resources with far-future expires headers.
#
# (!) If you don't control versioning with filename-based
# cache busting, you should consider lowering the cache times
# to something like one week.
#
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

then i tried to change style to check if it is cached but style changes on every load which means that there is no caching, then i thought my be it is the local server configurations so i moved to live one and agian still the same and it tested headers with [this site](https://redbot.org)
and i got this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Date: Sun, 24 Sep 2017 13:02:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Sun, 24 Sep 2017 13:02:51 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

**EDIT:**

I have found that mode_expires was not active on localhost and i enabled it but still facing the problem

Comment: maybe mod_expires is not active on your server, check it

Comment: i am sure it is active because i already use wordpress and it works and rewrites URLs normally

Comment: it's not the same module, we use **mod_rewrite** for redirection

Comment: sorry my mistake i meant it is already caching..sorry! fast reading

Comment: so if it's already working with wordpress where are you puting this small site ? on a sub directory ?

Comment: yes @Temani Afif

Comment: oh, it's localhost so ? there is no caching then. Why a cache system on localhost since the file are saved locally

Comment: i was trying to learn, So it wont work!? why then also not working on the live server?

Comment: i have noticed that if i opened the link inside new tab it keeps styles but only apply the new style if i clicked the reload icon.. i use Firefox.. maybe it clear the cache... is there any way to check weather a file is cached

Comment: using the console, you can see the network and when the file is load it tells you if it's from local or not ... can i have the link of the site ?

Comment: yes sure .. prosentra.com/test/t.php

Comment: getting this error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Your CSS file is not found

Comment: check now it was a problem with RewriteBase / which i changed to RewriteBase /test

Comment: i think it is the firefox button that clears the cache on reload because it is normal on chrome but please give it a try in your way

Comment: am using chrome and the file is not cached, did you try my answer below ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this part :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|gz)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
 </FilesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
</filesMatch>
# Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have added your code nothing new, try it your self

Comment: and you actived the mod_headers ?

Comment: How to activate it? i think it is activated but tell me how to make sure